scipy.integrate.nquad bounds from a class. TypeError: toy_class.gen_bounds.<locals>.x_bounds() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
I am trying to get the bounds of integration from a class and then pass those bounds to scipy.integrate.nquad, but there is a type error when calling either of the functions that return the bounds of integration.
The code needed to replicate this error is as follows:
from scipy.integrate import nquad

class toy_class():
    def gen_bounds(self):
        def x_bounds():
            return [-1 , 1]

        def y_bounds():
            return [-1 , 1]
        
        return x_bounds, y_bounds

xb, yb = toy_class().gen_bounds()

nquad(1, [xb, yb])

Which returns the following error:
TypeError: toy_class.gen_bounds.<locals>.x_bounds() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I assume the error arises because the functions are defined in a class and self is being passed as an argument to a function that takes no positional arguments. When including self in the initializer for either bounding function, this generates a new, unrelated error.
Defining x_bounds() and y_bounds() outside of the class fixes this issue, but I do not want them outside of the class. A difference I noticed between the functions defined inside the class and outside the class is the <locals> keyword added to the functions defined inside the class, so that may have something to do with the error.
I expect nquad(1, [xb, yb]) to return 4.0 (the area of a square from (-1,-1) to (1,1)).
Help would be very much appreciated!

The issue is not that the function is defined in a class. The issue that you're running into is that nquad is providing more flexibility here than you need.
When nquad is given callables for the range of integration, each callable receives arguments which represent the chosen value of every variable which comes after that variable.
This is very handy if, for example, you need to integrate over a circular region. Here is an example of what that could look like:
from scipy.integrate import nquad
import numpy as np

class toy_class():
    def gen_bounds(self):
        def x_bounds(y):
            d = np.sqrt(1 - y**2)
            return [-d, d]

        def y_bounds():
            return [-1, 1]

        return x_bounds, y_bounds

xb, yb = toy_class().gen_bounds()

nquad(lambda x, y: 1, [xb, yb])

But if you have constant bounds of integration, it's overkill.
Let's start by fixing this example:
from scipy.integrate import nquad

class toy_class():
    def gen_bounds(self):
        def x_bounds(y):
            return [-1 , 1]

        def y_bounds():
            return [-1 , 1]

        return x_bounds, y_bounds

xb, yb = toy_class().gen_bounds()

nquad(lambda x, y: 1, [xb, yb])

Notice that I added a y argument to x_bounds(). If you wanted to make the bounds that you integrate x over depend on the value of y, this is how you would do it.
But since you have constant bounds of integration, you don't need to provide a function at all. nquad has a shortcut for this. You can provide the bounds instead of a function which returns bounds.
from scipy.integrate import nquad

class toy_class():
    def gen_bounds(self):
        x_bounds = [-1, 1]
        y_bounds = [-1, 1]
        
        return x_bounds, y_bounds

xb, yb = toy_class().gen_bounds()

nquad(lambda x, y: 1, [xb, yb])


Thank you very much, this has solved this issue!
So the two takeaways are: nquad needs a function of the same dimension as the integral bounds to integrate over even if that function is constant and that the first set of bounds that are passed needs to have the other variable in the initializer.
On this being overkill, I do intend to integrate over a circular region, but simplified the problem to get to the root of it and will also have a more complicated integrand than 1.
Once again, thank you very much!

@JosephF.SpechtIV I added an example to the answer of how to integrate over the area of a circle.
